# Integrating Poisson distributions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

I'm trying to do the following

```
Integrate[Exp[-λ] λ^k/k!, {k, 0, ∞}]
```

The answer should be 1 but *Mathematica* is unable to do it. Same story when I try the expectation value (answer should be `λ`)

```
Integrate[Exp[-λ] λ^k/k!*k, {k, 0, ∞}]
```

It doesn't even work if I replace `λ` with a number, say 2.

Any pointers on what I should do to get *Mathematica* to evaluate?

Comment: You don't exactly integrate a *discrete* distribution, y'know…

Comment: How about replacing k! with Gamma[k+1]? That still doesn't work.

Comment: It certainly won't. Again, Poisson is a *discrete* distribution. Integrating is intended for *continuous* distributions. Replace `Integrate[]` with `Sum[]` and report back.

Comment: Ah I see your point. If you wanna make your comment an answer, I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*k* is a discrete random variable, where for this distribution *k* takes on the the values of the non-negative integers. So you sum over those, as opposed to integrating as you would for a continuous random variable:

```
In[1]:= Sum[(E^-λ λ^k)/k!, {k, 0, ∞}]

Out[1]= 1
```

Comment: Can you maybe expand on your answer to point out the difference between discrete and continuous distributions?

Comment: Looks like you just did in the comments above, but ok.

Comment: Now I don't have to write an answer, and can just upvote yours instead. Thanks! ;)